# Merge dataframes on header and index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe  `df1` with list of distribution centers, hq lines.  I've created a new dataframe `df2` that uses `DC_Name` as the index and `HQ_line` as the headers.  I'd like to replace the NaN in `df2` with the corresponding Field_Line from `df1`.  Sounds easy, but I'm not sure the best approach.

DF1

```
      DC_Name HQ_Line Field_Line
0  Albany, NY     AAC        NAC
1  Albany, NY     AC          AC
2  Albany, NY     ACB        ACK
3  Albany, NY     ACC        NaN
4  Albany, NY     ACE        ACK
```

DF2

```
                 AAC  AC   ACB  ACC  ACE  ACO  ACT  ADO  AIT  AKA ...   WWM
Albany, NY       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN   
Albuquerque, NM  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN   
Altoona, PA      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN   
Atlanta, GA      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN   
Birmingham, AL   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of your example doesn't match the input. But try this to see if it works for you:

```
df.pivot(index='DC_Name',columns='HQ_Line')
```

Comment: This is the way you should do it. You could add `values='Field_Line'` just to be explicit, otherwise this is how I would do it

Comment: Yeah those were .head() prints, should've mentioned that.  This solution worked perfectly.  Simple, exactly what I needed thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to simply use dictionaries and revamp your datasets around JSON, if you can (or simply parse your text files to build your datasets as python dictionaries).

Pseudocode would be:

```
df1 = [
 {"index" : "Albany, NY", "HQ" : "AAC", "value" : "NAC"},
 #etc.
]
```

and something like:

```
df2 = {
 "Albany, NY" : {
  "AAC" : None, # None is equiv. to your NaN
  #etc.
 }
}
```

Then build your dataset with something like:

```
for line in df1:
 index = line['index']
 hq = line['hq']
 value = line['value']
 df2[index][hq] = value
```